# mysql cannot create foreign key but with same data type

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to create tables with foreign keys, but I keep getting error 1215 saying that it cannot add foreign key constraint. I double checked the datatypes and the REFERENCES part of the constraint, and that seems to be in order.

I am relatively new to databases. what can i do to resolve the issue?

Patient table where FK will be referenced:

[image: This is the patient table where the foreign key will be referenced]

the admitting_diagnosis table which has successfully referenced the PK of patient table

[image: A successfully referenced table]

the radiology request table which I am trying to reference. i copied the create table code of admitting_diagnosis but throws me an error.

[image]

[image]

A sequence and a trigger created for the patient table. do you think this is the main cause?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post your code as pictures. That makes it hard for anyone to use that in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key should reference to primary key of the first table.  There is no primary key in patient table. You should create the primary KEY patient_id and reference  it in other two tables.

Comment: i have altered the patient table on the third picture. that is why i am able to reference it in the 2nd